# How do I determine the MIME type of a file?

Tags: bash, mime-type

I recently switched to  GNOME 3 and was surprised to find that there was no way by which we could set the default applications. I am writing a Nautilus extension using Bash. I want to find the MIME type of a file.

Initially I used to extract the extension of the file using `sed` and build the code on it. Then I realized that there is this command called `file`. When I try to find the `mime-type` of a `mkv` file, the command `file --mime-type -b <filename>` outputs `application/octet-stream` but when I see the Nautilus properties window it shows the correct `video/x-matroska` mime-type.

Am I missing anything here? If not is there a better way in which I can file the mime-type of a file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are different ways to get a MIME type on Linux, and they often lead to different results.  Use

```
xdg-mime query filetype your_file
```

to get the same MIME type as Nautilus gets.

Comment: Thanks! file command was working fine except for the mkv files.I just realized that there are two ways in which nautilus decides the file-types..the headers of a file and the extension! Lots of learning to do! :)

Comment: Technically Nautilus uses the [Shared MIME-info Database](http://standards.freedesktop.org/shared-mime-info-spec/shared-mime-info-spec-latest.html) to determine the MIME type of a file.

Answer (score -1):

Look up the .desktop file of the application (i.e. gedit) in /usr/share/applications and add the MIME-Types as following:

```
...
MimeType=text/plain;text/wiki;text/foo;
...
```

They should then be automatically launched on these files.